# How do I install an app that doesn't have models or views?

Tags: django

I am attempting to install and test django-honeypot from [sunlightlabs](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-honeypot) using the provided templates.

the application does not come accompanied with models nor views and I am confused as to how I am supposed to get the app to work. I have attempted to play with the urls to call the templates.

my mysite/mysite/urls.py follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', include('honeypot.urls')),
)
```

and my mysite/honeypot/urls.py follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
#from tagging.views import tagged_object_list
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', render, dict(template_name='/home/mohrashak/attribute2/honeypot/templates/honeypot/webpage.html'), name='price'),


)
ROOT_URLCONF="honeypot.urls"
```

where webpage is

```
{% load honeypot %}
<form>
{% render_honeypot_field "field_name" %}
</form>
```

and my understanding is that something will be entered into the box be processed using the application. But there is no model. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about models or views for django-honeypot. It is installed into the site-packages folder of your Python library so you don't have to write models/views/urls.py for you - these are all there in your pythonpath.

Make sure you read the [online documentation](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-honeypot) for installing the app.

Here is the checklist:

1. Add `honeypot` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py;
2. Define `HONEYPOT_FIELD_NAME` which is the name to use for the honeypot field in your form. Try not to use 'honeypot' though as some bots will avoid it.
3. Make sure you add `{% load honeypot %}` in the top of your template using django-honeypot;
4. Then use the following tag in any form `{% render_honeypot_field "field_name" %}`
5. When your form is submitted - you can use the `check_honeypot` decorator from `honeypot.decorators` to check the value is present (or not by default) and correct.

Here is the example from the documentation to add to *your view*:

```
from honeypot.decorators import check_honeypot

@check_honeypot(field_name='hp_field_name')
def post_comment(request):
    ...

@check_honeypot
def other_post_view(request):
    ...
```

#### Edit1:

In response to your comment:

1. Yes;
2. Yes.
3. No - the nature of `django-honeypot` is that it prevents "form spam". So you have to have at least a form in your template. You should pass a form from a view to a template. More information [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/). I've written a near full example below.

#### Example of a contact form using django-honeypot

Note: This is untested.

This is an example that creates and shows a contact form (by going to a `/contact/` URL) and then handles the form being submitted. Imagine we have used `django_admin.py startapp contact_app`

`urls.py`

Your urls file takes the `/contact/` URL passes the request to our `contact` view.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^contact/$', 'contact_app.views.contact'),
)
```

`contact_app/views.py`

Your views file takes the request, and handles `GET` and `POST` requests. If the request is a `GET` it passes an empty form to the template. If a `POST` then it checks the form is valid and processes the form. We wrap it in the `check_honeypot` decorator to make sure it passes our `django-honeypot` test.

```
from contact_app.forms import ContactForm
from honeypot.decorators import check_honeypot

@check_honeypot
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'my_form': form,
    })
```

`contact_app/forms.py`

Here we specify the form fields that are going to be required and display in the template.

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

`templates/contact.html`

From our view, we pass our form (called `my_form`) to our template and use django's templating language to render each field as a `<p></p>`. We also load the honeypot and insert the necessary field.

```
{% load honeypot %}

<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ my_form.as_p }}
{% render_honeypot_field "field_name" %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: alright let me make sure that I actually understand you.
1. in mysite.mysite.settings.py I add 'honeypot' to INSTALLED_APPS
2.in mysite.mysite.settings.py I add HONEYPOT_FIELD_NAME='myname'
3.in mysite.honeypot.templates.honeypot.webpage.html I leave the file as is(supposing that I want to use an empty template to test)
4.(I am using a clean project mysite that has absolutely no views, so i will use the urls as mentioned before or use the admin app if you suggest so)
5. in mysite.mysite.views.py I add your code
did I get that right?

Comment: I have added a full example using a contact form and `django-honeypot` to my answer.

Comment: I would love to thank you for the great answer that you have given. However I have followed your method and I get the 400 bad request page, any clues?

Comment: I'm afraid with such limited information I can't help you. This is an untested example with an idea of how to use the module as per your original question. If you're using the django `manage.py runserver` then enable `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py` to try and provide you with mor information.

Comment: So, by sending the submit button I am forced to be routed to mysite.honeypot.templates.errorpage.html and DEBUG=True by default. Thank you very much kisamoto